# How to use DropoutWrapper in LSTM training and decoding

Tags: tensorflow

When I used dropout mechanism for lstm, the rouge score and loss of no dropout model performs better than model with dropout. So I wonder is my dropout code correct? I use tensorflow 0.12

```
  cellClass = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell
  for layer_i in xrange(hps.enc_layers):
    with tf.variable_scope('encoder%d'%layer_i), tf.device(
        self._next_device()):
      #bidirectional rnn cell
      cell_fw = cellClass(
          hps.num_hidden
          ,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.1, 0.1, seed=123),
          state_is_tuple=False
      )
      cell_bw = cellClass(
          hps.num_hidden
          ,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.1, 0.1, seed=113),
          state_is_tuple=False
      )
      cell_fw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell_fw, input_keep_prob=hps.input_dropout, output_keep_prob=hps.output_dropout)
      cell_bw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell_bw, input_keep_prob=hps.input_dropout, output_keep_prob=hps.output_dropout)
      (emb_encoder_inputs, fw_state, _) = tf.nn.bidirectional_rnn(
          cell_fw, cell_bw, emb_encoder_inputs, dtype=tf.float32,
          sequence_length=article_lens)
    #decoder
    cell = cellClass(
        hps.num_hidden
        ,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.1, 0.1, seed=113),
        state_is_tuple=False
        )
    cell=tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell, input_keep_prob=hps.input_dropout, output_keep_prob=hps.output_dropout)
    decoder_outputs, self._dec_out_state, self.cur_attns, self.cur_alpha = seq2seq.attention_decoder(
        emb_decoder_inputs, self._dec_in_state,  self._enc_top_states,
        cell, num_heads=1, loop_function=loop_function,
        initial_state_attention=initial_state_attention)
```

When training I set those keep prob to be the value I use like 0.5, when computing the loss of training set and validation set I keep them as 0.5, but in decoding step I use 1, which did not dropout anything. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Almost!

When you calculate the accuracy and validation, you need to manually set the keep_probability to 1.0 so that you don't actually drop any of your weight values when you are evaluating your network. If you don't do this, you'll essentially miscalculate the value you've trained your network to predict thus far. This could certainly negatively affect your acc/val scores. Especially with a 50% dropout rate.

Your dropout layer used in the decoding step is optional and should be experimented with. If you do use it, you'll want to set it to something other than 1.0.

Just to recap for the passerby, the idea behind dropout is to reset the values of random weights across your network weights to increase the probability that neurons don't become erroneously fixed (or whatever term you prefer) which results in over fitting of your network. Remember that, generally speaking, we are trying to approximate, or fit, our networks to a function. Since fitting networks is, in essence, an optimization problem, we have to to worry about optimizing to a local minima (or maxima... depending on which way the picture is oriented in your mind). Dropout is thus a form of regularization that helps us avoid over fitting.

If anyone has any further insights or corrections, please post!